# Migrating a large, manually managed AWS account into Terraform configuration

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I’m looking for any case studies, guides, or examples of bringing a relatively large, manually managed AWS account into Terraform. I’m looking to learn from others before doing this myself.

I’d like to inventory all the things and then progressively build the configuration and import.

I feel like I’m going to end up generating an inventory from Billing invoices, because there is no nice CLI way to generate a resource list that I can push into a CSV.

Any examples out there for me to read?

Comment: Have you checked [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) which can help you generate TF code from existing resources?

Comment: People generally use Google's Terraformer for this. This question is asked periodically, so there are others in the same boat as you. Whenever I do this for companies, the initial terraformer execution is indeed (like you said) generally just for a "global read" on your resources and a starting point, and then you would want to build your own config and state from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question and probably a lot of organizations are suffering from this. In case of the small number of resources, I would import the resource into the existing state and write a block of terraform code to start managing it, however for an enterprise solution you might want to try something like [Terraforming Tool](http://%20https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming).

To get the list of resources, [I havent tried it but check this out](https://github.com/JohannesEbke/aws_list_all)

Comment: Unfortunately, terraforming doesn't support many AWS resources. In this case, ECS isn't covered at all. It still does a solid job of covering 80%.